# Bootstrap Dual Listbox - cannot add item back once moved from selected listbox to unselected listbox

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am using BS dual listbox that contains same items as in a dropdown list (they represent different properties, one represents "owner" and listbox would represent list of participants.

I have an onChange for dropdownlist that (supposedly) marks the dropdown selected item in listbox as "selected".

The problem I am facing is: it works fine the first time I select a user, User A, from dropdown list; it adds it to selected listbox. Then I select another user from dropdown, User B, and it is also added. Next I move User A from selected listbox to unselected listbox. Now, when I select User A again from dropdown, it is not added again; if I select User C, it is fine but not User A.

This is what I have, and have tried:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="dlbx_Participants" name="dlbx_Participants" class="aiPart" title="Participants">
</select>

// Create Participants Dual Listbox
aiPart = $('.aiPart').bootstrapDualListbox({
    nonSelectedListLabel: 'Available Users',
    selectedListLabel: 'Assigned Users',
    preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
    moveOnSelect: false
});

$(document).on('change', '#ddlAIOwner', function () {debugger
    if (this.value != "-1") {
        // Trying to unselect first, if already selected
        $('#dlbx_Participants option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('selected', false);
        //$('#dlbx_Participants option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
        $('.aiPart').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);

        $('#dlbx_Participants option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('selected', true);
        $('.aiPart').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Comment: Anyone? Hopelessly stuck! Thinking about ditching BS Dual Listbox and look for something more robust with half decent documentation.

Comment: Same here... :(